# PHP Joining string and number - for loop

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, join

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++){ 
    $myarray = array();
    $subname = $sub. $i;       // Here i need help
    $myarray["sub".$i]   = $subname;
}
```

I need the output in the following format

> Note : I need to combine " $ " , " sub " and " $i " to create php var -> $sub1

```
$myarray["sub1"] = $sub1;
$myarray["sub2"] = $sub2;
$myarray["sub3"] = $sub3;
$myarray["sub4"] = $sub4;
```

Comment: you want to dynamically create a variable?

Comment: But what value $sub1 will have?

Comment: yes i need dynamic var and $sub1 has string "sub1"

Comment: @ARUN.G, you can checkout my answer. But I doubt how, $sub1 will have "sub1" string?

Comment: @ARUN.G Please see my answer. There is a way to dynamically create and assign a number of variables

Comment: What's in `$myarray` ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `${'a' . 'b'}`

```
$myarray["sub".$i]   = ${'sub'. $i }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to create dynamic variable names, if it is you can use `${"sub".$i}`

```
$myarray = array();
$sub1 = "something";
for ($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++){     
    $subname = ${"sub".$i};
    $myarray["sub".$i]   = $subname;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To dynamically generate a number of variables you can use this syntax:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++){ 
   ${"sub". $i} = "sub".$i;
}
```

So now `$sub1` is equal to `sub1` and so on

Answer (score 0):

Check this code

```
<?php
$myarray = array();
for ($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++){
    $sub = 'sub'.$i;
    $myarray["sub".$i]   = $$sub;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($myarray);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

for ($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++){
    $myarray = array();
    $subname = '$sub'. $i;       // Here i need help
    $myarray["sub".$i]   = $subname;
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($myarray);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

And the output is :

```
Array
(
    [sub1] => $sub1
)
Array
(
    [sub2] => $sub2
)
Array
(
    [sub3] => $sub3
)
Array
(
    [sub4] => $sub4
)
```